# How can I remove Paragon NTFS completely from my Mac?

Tags: ntfs

I deleted all files from **Application**, **Finder/Application Support**, and also removed it from **System Preference**. But I am still getting the notifications from it when I open my computer.

My activity Monitor shows that the notification files are saved in:
**/Library/Application Support/Paragon Software/com.paragon-software.ntfs.notification-agent.app/Contents/MacOS/NotificationAgent**

HOWEVER, I couldn't see **Paragon Software** in **/Library/Application Support**. I guess that is because the folder is hidden. Is there anyway I can see the hidden folder without downloading any other tool? Or how can I remove Paragon NTFS completely and not receive its notification anymore?

In notification settings, I can still see:
[image]
I can turn off the notification for now. But I really want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

To show hidden files:

Go to Finder-apps-utilis-terminal

Enter:

**defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES**

Press alt & right click finder app icon from dock. Then click relaunch

If you are using OS version >= Sierra, you can use

CMD + SHIFT + .

when in finder to show hidden files(Hit once more to revert)